# Using pivotal quantities for transformed parameters

Tags: confidence-interval, pivot

##### Setup

Suppose we have some iid data $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ that arises from a distribution with parameters $\theta$ and $\rho$. $\theta$ is the parameter of interest, and $\rho$ is a nuisance parameter. Suppose further that we know a pivotal quantity $h(X_1, \ldots, X_n ; \theta)$ that has a known distribution that's free of $\theta$ and $\rho$.

To get a confidence interval interval, typically we start off by calculating some quantiles $L_{\alpha}$ and $U_{\alpha}$ such that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[h(X_1, \ldots, X_n ; \theta) \in (L_{\alpha},U_{\alpha}) \right] = 1-\alpha,
$$
and then rearranging to
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[\theta \in (L'(X_1,\ldots, X_N),U'(X_1,\ldots, X_N)) \right] = 1-\alpha
$$
in order to find the interval $(L'(X_1,\ldots, X_N),U'(X_1,\ldots, X_N))$.

##### Question

Now suppose I'm interested in finding intervals of the form
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[ |\theta| \in [0,\tilde{U}(X_1,\ldots, X_N)) \right] = 1-\alpha
$$

**Is there a theorem that guarantees (or precludes) the existence of intervals of this form?**

I know that if I find a pivotal for $\theta' = |\theta|$, then I can do this. But is there more to say about when I can/can't do it using the pivotal for the untransformed/canonical parameter?

As another example, Bayesian credible intervals of this form are always obtainable as long as you have a proper posterior. You can just use the transformation theorem and get the posterior for the new transformed parameter.

Comment: Are the quantiles $L_{\alpha}, U_{\alpha}$ given or are you able to calculate them in some way?

Comment: @Spätzle you get them from looking them up in a table or using a quantile function in some software package

Comment: So why not constructing a symmetrical CI in the form $P[\theta\in[-K_\alpha, K_\alpha]]=1-\alpha$? This is perfectly equal to $P[|\theta|\in[0, K_\alpha]]=1-\alpha$

Comment: @Spätzle that would be a rephrasing of my question: "when can/can't you have an interval from $P[\theta\in[-K_\alpha, K_\alpha]]=1-\alpha$"?